# How to use useI18n inside vue3 composition api?

Tags: internationalization, vuejs3, i18next, vue-i18n

I'm using `vue-i18n` in conjunction with `quasar + vue 3 composition api` but I get an error as following

```js
SyntaxError: 19 vendor.49822a76.js:formatted:926 SyntaxError: 19 (at vendor.49822a76.js:formatted:27825:21)
at F (vendor.49822a76.js:formatted:27825:21)
at Pt (vendor.49822a76.js:formatted:29590:20)
at vn (vendor.49822a76.js:formatted:30617:27)
at 238.35491042.js:1:419
at f (vendor.49822a76.js:formatted:883:25)
at p (vendor.49822a76.js:formatted:892:27)
```

[Error In console when using useI18n](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNYh7.png)
and here is my i18n file:

Boot directory:

```js
import { boot } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import { createI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import messages from 'src/i18n'

export default boot(({ app }) => {
  const i18n = createI18n({
    locale: 'ar',
    messages
  })

  // Set i18n instance on app
  app.use(i18n)
})
```

My Vue File

```js
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';
import AppService from "../../services/api";


export default defineComponent({
  setup() {
    const { t } = useI18n();
   
    console.log(t)
   }
})
```

any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You need specify allowComposition: true to createI18n options.

[Here](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/guide/migration/vue3.html#migration-to-composition-api-from-legacy-api) is the link to the documentaion

Comment: Link-only answers have risk of link going dead. Please consider providing summary/steps from link to solve the problem.